# Metoid Prime Trilogy freezes when starting Metroid Prime 3

Tags: nintendo-wii, metroid-prime-trilogy

When i'm trying to start Metroid Prime 3 my Wii freezes, is this a problem with my disk or does my Wii has a problem (I've got a launch-date Wii)

Don't know if it is related, but in Metroid Prime, in the chozo ruins, when I shoot the sap sacs the game halts, goes black, and continues again, but with no animation of the sac exploding.

Comment: Wooo, thats a good one. I have the same game and haven't had a single problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metroid Prime Trilogy uses a Dual-layer disk, which some (older) Wii consoles have trouble reading.

Most likely, the source of the problems is a dirty lens, which may be solved by using the Wii Lens Cleaning Kit.

Alternatively, You can contact Nintendo, as they are aware of this problem and (usually) repair your Wii for free.

Comment: i remember hearing about a lot of people having this problem when smash bros brawl came out, as it was one of the first major dual-layer releases

Comment: @kip try searching for Metroid Prime Trilogy freeze on google -> http://ahb.me/pH0